# By what generic method do we correctly determine that an analytical expression of language is true?

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-language

The answer to this is a philosophy of logic question would seem to unify the notion of analytic truth across all formal and natural languages. This subject of this question seems to refer to the analytic subset of Truthmaker theory.

> A stipulative definition is a type of definition in which a new or
> currently existing term is given a new specific meaning for the
> purposes of argument or discussion in a given context.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stipulative_definition

Within the scope of the question {analytic truth} is stipulated to mean any expression of (formal or natural) language that can be completely verified as true entirely on the basis of its meaning. It is closely related to self-evident truth.

> Analytic propositions are true or not true solely by virtue of their
> meaning...
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction

> Truth-conditional semantics is an approach to semantics of natural
> language that sees meaning (or at least the meaning of assertions) as
> being the same as, or reducible to, their truth conditions.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics

**Thus analytic meaning is defined as:**
Every truth that can be expressed using language and verified as
completely true entirely on the basis of other expressions of language is a truth verified as true entirely on the basis of its meaning.

> In epistemology (theory of knowledge), a self-evident proposition is a
> proposition that is known to be true by understanding its meaning
> without proof. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-evidence

**Thought experiment:** Try and provide any example of an expression of language that is known to be true entirely on the basis of its meaning that cannot be proved to be true entirely on the basis of its meaning.

**By what generic method do we correctly determine that an analytical expression of language is true?**

Comment: The generic method is thinking about what things mean.

Comment: Which language? Even for a formal language with precise rules describing which expressions are synonymous, such an algorithm may not exist. Something as simple and precise as the [word problem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) is undecidable in general, for example. In natural languages, this is further complicated by loose grammar, vague, ambiguous and incoherent "meanings", etc., so you can forget about any "generic method".

Comment: @Conifold Undecidable does not count as true. My question only refers to the subset of expressions of language that are correctly determined to be true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CycL Formalizes natural language quite well. Rudolf Carnap meaning postulates also work for simple expressions. For example when the new term Bachelor is defined on the basis of existing terms {Married, Adult, Male} we only need a negation operator to complete its definition: **Bachelor(x) ≡ (Adult(x) ∧ Male(x) ∧ ¬Married(x))** thus the term Bachelor is defined in terms of its constituents.

Comment: @DavidGudeman "The generic method is thinking about what things mean." Yes that seems correct. (a) What steps are involved?  (b) How could these steps be specified as an algorithm?

Comment: A question attempts to solicit answers and does not have any other goals. Your very introduction makes me think that this is another one of your hopeless attempts of promoting your views.

Comment: Question: *Has a dog Buddha-nature?* Answer: *Mu!* Some people think the purpose of Zen koans is to play a social game between the Master and students (like paying for psychotherapy or some other mode of interaction with deference to an external authority figure). To me the student is trying to assign truth-values with the discriminating mind that invents two categories (dogs; Buddha-nature) and truth-values (True; False). Neural networks seem to generate cognitive maps and try to assign truth-values. Leave it at that. The answer, Mu!, to me means *No comment!* Buddha-nature transcends truth!

Answer (score 2):

Willard Van Orman Quine's famous paper *Two Dogmas of Empiricism* (1951) showed that the notion of an analytic truth can be defined in reference to the notion of synonymy or meaning, but there is no clear criterion for either notion and the usual explanations ("true by definition" - which definition? etc.) fail to be precise. Carnap, Grice and Stawson famously argued against it in *Meaning and Truth in Natural Languages* (Carnap) and *In Defense of a Dogma* (Grice and Strawson). Quine's response to both articles and other polemics - the book *Word and Object* - also contained a rough definition of analycity based on the notion of *stimulus meaning* (outlined in the second chapter, which is the heart of the book). Nowadays the debate is considered generally settled, with logical empiricism long dead, but there have been some proposals since. Notably, by Chalmers (*Revisability and Conceptual Change in "Two Dogmas of Empiricism"* and also *Constructing the World*) and David Lewis (*Convention*).

I think Chalmers' proposal is interesting, although it doesn't provide a notion analycity strong enough to challenge Quine's contribution. It's also not at all complex, if you know basic Bayesianism. The definition goes:

[Chalmers' definition:] sentence S is analytic if and only if cr(S) is high and, for every piece of possible evidence E, cr(S | E) is also high

In other words, sentence S is analytic if no evidence will cause one to significantly lower one's credence in it.

Comment: Maybe this addresses the issues that you raised: Every truth that can be expressed using language and verified as completely true entirely on the basis of other expressions of language <is> a truth verified as true entirely on the basis of its meaning.

Comment: @polcott That is not what either of these men meant. Evidence is never purely semantical since without *practical implications*, language is hollow, thin, nothing but smoke and mirrors. Meaning is holistic, yes, but it is also malleable as our practical relations to one another and the world change.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Evidence is on the other side of the analytic/synthetic divide, I am referring to tautologies. Tautology, in logic, a statement so framed that it cannot be denied without inconsistency. 

https://www.britannica.com/topic/tautology 


This is deductive rather than inductive inference, thus the coherence rather than correspondence theory of truth applies.

Comment: @polcott Indeed, but tautologies (like A = A) are distinct from full-blown analytic statements (like "All bachelors are unmarried").

Comment: @abcga "Thus, “All humans are mammals” is held to assert with regard to anything whatsoever that either it is not a human or it is a mammal. But that universal “truth” follows not from any facts noted about real humans but only from the actual use of human and mammal and is thus purely a matter of definition." https://www.britannica.com/topic/tautology

Comment: @polcott Which definition? I can define "human" in many different ways. That's exactly Quine's point - there are no "meanings". Saying that it is "how <<human>> and <<mammal>> are used" doesn't explain anything, because they're correctly used whenever a true sentence is asserted. And not every true sentence is analytic. Saying that they don't depend on matters of facts also doesn't explain anything, because in conjunction with other sentences it has observational consequences etc.

Comment: @abcga **"purely a matter of definition"** When we hypothesize that the complete model of the world is encoded in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CycL that can encode Rudolf Carnap Meaning Postulates. Thus creating an inheritance hierarchy tree of knowledge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science) The Cyc project uses 128-bit GUIDs for each unique sense meaning. Thus we hypothesize that the complete body of human general knowledge of "humans" and "animals" is already available. The above article is implying such a system.

Comment: @polcott Yes, if you have a totality of "meaning postulates", then any sentence that can be derived from them is analytic (the way you encode these doesn't seem very important). But then I don't understand the point of your question. I thought you were asking about a criterion applicable seamlessly to natural languages.

Comment: @abcga Do we seem to have the (underlying infrastructure) framework to propose an answer?

Comment: @polcott I don't think so. I don't believe in any suitable criterion of analyticity.

Comment: @abcga I can see how it all fits together as a single tree of knowledge as a mutually interlocking semantic tautology.

Comment: @polcott I am unsure what are you talking about at this point.

Comment: @abcga It seems that the entire body of analytic truth is merely a connected set of semantic tautologies.

Answer (score 0):

**The overview of the framework of a possible solution**
Analyticity is most unequivocally defined as any expression of formal or natural language that is proven to be true entirely on the basis of its relation to other expressions of language that are known to be true.

The most general way to express the notion of a formal axiomatic system seems to be anchored in finite string transformation rules. Systems such as Montague Grammar and the CycL language of the Cyc project encode natural language semantics directly in finite strings. These systems had Rudolf Carnap Meaning postulates as their predecessor.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CycL 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montague_grammar
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning_postulate

Within systems such as these the term Bachelor(x) can be defined as (Male(x) ∧ Adult(x) ∧ ¬Married(x)) thus within this axiomatic system we can see that Bachelor(x) semantically entails ¬Married(x) (and two other things).

When-so-ever one expression X is semantically entailed by other expressions defined to be true, (through a sequence of finite string transformation rules that process semantic entailment) then X is proved to be true.